# Is it possible to share `Directory.Build.props` between Net Full and Net Standard projects in the same folder?

Tags: msbuild, .net-standard-2.0

I created a .NET 4.0 project assembly in a folder, and also created a .NET Standard project file in the same folder (to share the same `.cs` files).  It works perfectly until I add a `Directory.Build.props` file, at which point I get this error on the .NET 4.0 project only:

> Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"
>   framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" in the
>   "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet
>   restore.

I tried a file with only the project element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
</Project>
```

alse also

```
<Project Condition='$(MSBuildProjectName.Contains("-Standard"))'>
```

I get the same error.

I already know one solution is to create a shared project and include the files that way, or add linked files, but I wanted to see if I could use `Directory.Build.props` ONLY for .Net Standard projects in the same folder to change some NET Standard-ONLY configurations.  If not I'll have to split up the projects into separate folders (this was just an experiment really to see if it's possible).

The reason for `Directory.Build.props` for the Net Standard project is because I cannot use the `.csproj` file to change the output directories without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this does work.  I closed Visual Studio, deleted all the `obj` and `bin` folders, including the `.vs` folder in the parent directory, then restarted Visual Studio. I added this to the `Directory.Build.props` file so it only runs for the NET Standard projects with `-Standard` in the name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition='$(MSBuildProjectName.Contains("-Standard"))'>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\obj_std\</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

***Note:*** If you use this, you'll have to change `-Standard` to whatever suffix you add to your .Net Standard projects, or otherwise work out a new condition.

I found out the reason it fails is because of this file:

```
obj\project.assets.json
```

It gets created when .Net Core builds in the same directory. It must have gotten left in there before I changed the `obj` directory name.

After more research I found this, in which a post seems to do the same thing I just did above (I figured this out on my own before finding the page below):
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5126#issuecomment-297457667